# Getting Asset validation failed when trying to submit app to App Store Connect

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

I get this error when I try to uplload an app to App Store Connect. How can I fix it?

> Missing Info.plist value. The Info.plist key 'BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers' must contain a list of identifiers used to submit and handle tasks when 'UIBackgroundModes' has a value of 'processing'. For more information, refer to the Information Property List Key Reference at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html. (ID: e37045c7-535f-4b6d-b87b-f409ebf1abd9)

Comment: The error seems clear. Did you read the linked documentation and update your Info.plist accordingly?